# How to know if a Wordpress plugin requires .htaccess file?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, nginx

I am planning to set up my server in the Cloud with Nginx and also use Wordpress,but it seems Nginx does not support .htaccess file.So how do I know if a Wordpress plugin requires .htaccess file?

Hoping that if I know which plugin that I am going to use requires the .htaccess file I might be able to take some measures to ensure that the plugin runs smoothly with Nginx.

Comment: WordPress itself uses `.htaccess`, though you could probably replicate the rules in Nginx format. I would be inclined to search for "WordPress and Nginx" to see if this has been done before - it surely must have done.

Comment: Alternatively, you could proxy from NginX to a separate Apache instance running locally on another port, assuming you're not under tight RAM constraints.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to use Nginx as stand alone server so,you may first ask yourself ,what you need exactly at your wordpress site? how many plugins you need and why? then look for those plugins that have ready-made setup to be compatible with Nginx but doing that this way, without Self-skills, will restrict your options.

The `.htaccess` is a configuration file that could do lots of different configuration (Actually not all) in Apache server without going every time to server config files ,and as you said , there is no such a way in Nginx and you should be able to handle that in server config file.

They could be compatible if you have skills and time to do that,otherwise go to another option by using Nginx as a reverse-proxy in front of Apache .